# Question regarding an Op-Amp substitution

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, variable

[image: 10a variable voltage regulator]

This schematic has a LM107 op-amp at its heart. It seems that it is now discontinued. Will a uA741 op-amp be a good substitute? If not, why not? What would be a good substitute? 
Thanks.

Comment: This post is closed.

Comment: Too bad, this is kind of an interesting question.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. The "duplicate" is a general discussion, and I suggest that it requires more skill in the art that the poster possesses, which makes it useless from his point of view.